# Logic to find states in an Enum

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, enums, boolean-logic

I have a method that brings in an Enum value as an argument.

```
enum {
   UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask                     = 0,
   UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask          = 1 << 0,
   UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask   = 1 << 1
};
```

There are four possible values:

1. Only `UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask` is true.
2. Only `UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask` is true.
3. Only `UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask` is ture.
4. **Both** `UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask` **AND** `UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask` are true.

That last possibility is the one I'm having trouble with. What statement will return true if and only if the two last options are true????

(This is Objective-C code btw)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int mask=UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask|UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask;
BOOL result=(value&mask)==mask;
```

or just

`(value&0x03)==0x03`

if you're feeling lazy :)